# How to add ring back tone support in PSTN network

Tags: ss7

How to add ring back tone support in PSTN network for fix telephone owners to select a tone or music for peoples call her/his number. The network switching protocol is SS7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common approach is to include in the ACM the "*Optional backward call indicators*" (Q.763/3.37) and set the bit A to 1. This sets "*in-band information or an appropriate pattern is now available*", like used for announcements with no answer.
It worked with lot of switches (at least on ITU-T world).